# Count amount of non-blank cells & if contains a certain character minus a value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of text values which I have used COUNTA to count the filled cells. I also need to identify if there is a "*", and if so minus the count by 0.5.

So far I have tried (and a few variations of):

```
 =IF(SEARCH("~*",C05:C52),COUNTA(C05:C52)-0.5,COUNTA(C05:C52))
```

But this comes up with #VALUE! - I've looked at similar examples but cant get this to work - I am obviously missing something obvious!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses COUNTA to count the non-blank values in C5:C52 and subtracts 0.5 for every value containing an asterisk.

```
=COUNTA(C5:C52)-SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND("~", SUBSTITUTE(C5:C52, "*", "~")))*0.5)
```

Answer (score 4):

If some of the cells don't have an asterisk, `SEARCH` will return `#VALUE!`. Use `IFERROR` to catch them. Also, make sure you enter it as an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=COUNTA(C5:C52)-IF(SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH("~*",C5:C52),0)),0.5)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I hadn't considered that about the IFERROR - thanks for explaining. :)